# Why should I use Cards in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot find out why I should use Card (instead of Container, for example) in Dart and what they are meant for.

I'm trying to build a simple TODO application.

I'm returning a Column widget filled with Cards created from a List<String>.
The question comes when I want to customize the Card sizes. I cannot directly change the Card dimensions (and other properties I think), so principally I have to insert my card in a container and modify it through it.

- Why not create a container from the beginning?
- Why do they use Card in all tutorials for these kind of things?
- What are they designed for?

Comment: I think Card is just something to help in most cases, because you can use a title, subtitle, images, etc. But you can create your own "card" with container and everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container is a layout widget.
Card is a visual widget.

You can use both. They have different purposes. Card is mainly the Flutter equivalent of Material [Cards](https://material.io/components/cards/)

Comment: So card are meant for displaying elements, instead container are meant to organize elements? Why did you refer to card as an element and not as a widget? Thank you

Comment: Yes. As for the "element", I've changed it to "widget".